# How would a world composed entirely of androids evolve?

Tags: evolution, technological-development, robots

Could something like this be possible? All humans have been replaced with highly advanced androids, indiscernible from humans, which have been implanted with the memories of the humans they were based on. They are exact copies of the real humans. What implications would this provide, and how would they continue to evolve? Assuming the world right now was this world, with internet and all the virtues of daily life, what would happen then?

Assuming the androids in question are indiscernible on the outside, but on the inside are almost indestructible (can still be crushed by weights, but can move 3x the amount humans can, and can survive falls etc.) How would the population react to this?

Comment: I assume these androids still reproduce the same way as normal humans? And they still die the same way too?

Comment: "evolve" is an interesting word here... I'm assuming your robots can't reproduce as humans do?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, and they also can't die unless they reccieve a serious injury (e.g being crushed). They don't require food or oxygen, but do have to "recharge" by sleeping 2 hours a day.

Comment: Do they _know_ that they are robots?

Comment: @CitadelCore Here's the thing, we're not in your mind. You need to tell us all these properties before you invite people to answer what we assume is a complete question.

Comment: Not at first, they have to first discover it as in Samuel's post, which would invoke mass panic, and once everyone knew it would die down and everyone would accept the reality that they're robots. So, let's say yes.

Comment: @Samuel Alright, I'm sort of new to Worldbuilding and the whole StackExchange thing. Anyway, thanks for the answers.

Comment: @CitadelCore No problem. I suggest trying out the [Question Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/656/3202). You can post a proposed question there and find out if you're missing any vital information. This will eventually help you properly communicate your ideas, an excellent skill to have in life.

Comment: Arnold Schwarzenegger would be elected governor.

Answer (score 3):

**Mass panic.**

Now that these androids are discernible from humans in many ways, have significantly more strength, and can't be easily killed: people are going to notice right away. Panic and existential hysteria will sweep the globe. People will think they're dreaming. Society will collapse. Everything everywhere will change.

---

*Original answer:*

**Nothing would change.**

They're "exact copies of the real humans". They think they're humans, they act like humans, they are "indiscernible from humans".

It literally could have happened already, *twice*, and we would have no way of knowing.

Comment: What if they found out? It would invoke a major panic, wouldn't it?

Comment: @CitadelCore How could they find out? They're indiscernible from humans.

Comment: If someone falls off a cliff (and dosen't die). Indiscernible, in the sense that if you looked at them, you couldn't tell the difference, but inside they're literally robots.

Comment: I'm going to add more to my original post because I don't think I included enough detail.

Comment: @CitadelCore Not being able to die or having robotic innards is pretty damn discernible from humans.

Comment: Yeah, but what do you think would happen if in one second the population of the entire world was changed to these "androids". It would take some time for someone to discover that they're actually robots, and then, would it invoke some kind of domino effect and everyone would eventually find out? Plus, they're almost indestructible, so it could be attributed to supernatural causes if they for example survived a long fall.